# Patroni set up for the pg Cluster

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, patroni

I have written a patroni.yml to the rocky 8.9 os to the /etc/patroni.yml

so i also written /etc/systemd/system/patroni.service so after all i
run the my patroni it is working if i see the
systemctl status patroni.service everything is ok, also
systemctl status postgrespro-std-16 is working (set up by patroni) this is same with my other 3 patroni members and also binded the ports which is 5432

so main problem is that

```
+ Cluster: pg-ha-cluster (7337187168991802534) ----+-----------+
| Member  | Host          | Role    | State   | TL | Lag in MB |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| pp_pg_1 | 192.168.10.1  | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |
| pp_pg_2 | 192.168.10.2  | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |
| pp_pg_3 | 192.168.10.3  | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |
| pp_pg_4 | 192.168.10.4  | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
```

everything is stoped

I checked all log files, even turned on the debug, so there is no any negative logs everything is showing success.

what be the solution for this?

1. Installed patroni
2. Installed the postgres
3. Wrote a patroni.yml
4. Wrote a systemd for patroni

Comment: This is not about programming or software development. Besides, it lacks crucial information (like, how is the distributed consensus store set up?).

Comment: https://github.com/vitabaks/postgresql_cluster

this github repo can help to set up postgres cluster with several os